# How to Download The same Link for Two Times?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i written Code to Download File , 
it's Downloading first path  But it's not Downloading Second Path.

```
function Download(){   
   (i = 0; i < 2; i++){
      window.location.href = '/Uploads/Resume/' + i + '/RAj.docx';
   }
}
```

Comment: Apart from what adeneo mentioned, you miss a `for` I supose, and always use `var` to the iterator variable.

Comment: Open them in new windows. You can't have two URLs in the same one.

Comment: It is not the same Link as you tell in your title. First file is Resume/0 and second is Resume/1

Comment: @Shomz - actually, thinking about it, you can if the URL's are sending the correct headers back.

Comment: As they are are not html files, yes window.open

Comment: @adeneo True, but you'd rely on browser's mime-types. If the browser decides to show it instead of attempting to download it, you'll never see the second one as the first one would be rendered. And besides, I think there's a protection against multiple downloads occuring from the same event.

Comment: @Shomz - That's true, but assuming the correct content disposition etc. is set and the file really does download when clicking the link, iterating this way should work.

Comment: @Shomz, yes just trying to explain in a comment, that by giving the window.open a 'name' parameter, it can run (silently) some extra cases in this event

Comment: @RobSedgwick Sure thing. I wonder if display/download functionality can be controlled somehow. I believe Chrome displays a doc in a new tab when you left click a link, and everything else triggers the download. I know we don't have anchors here, but I wonder if we could reproduce that functionality. My gut feeling is that window.open would force a download.

Answer (score 3):

Try this using [**window.open()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.open):

```
function download(){   
   for(var i = 0; i < 2; i++){
      window.open('/Uploads/Resume/' + i + '/RAj.docx');
   }
}
```

Comment: It's open in new window and download one File but i need Two file to download at a time..

Comment: You don't need the focus, the idea is to start two downloads.

Comment: ( just if the browser had the ability to display the doc inside it directly was the reason ) - these are docx, viewable in the browser in many cases.

Answer (score 1):

`window.location.href` redirects your current `window` to the new URL, so all JavaScript stops to execute.

You can use a solution similar to @Sergio's solution: (see [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g4PXv/))

```
var download = function () {
    for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        var wnd = window.open('http://www.google.com/search?q=' + i);
        wnd.focus();
    }

    return false;
};
```

document.getElementById('a').onclick = download;

Or download your data using `XMLHttpRequest`, but probably it's a better choice to use a framework like jQuery, see [`jQuery.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).